# Motorcycle won't turn over in rain?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, starting, cranks-wont-run

Recently my motorcycle(cb600f 1998) won't start after being out in the rain.
The starter motor turns over but the engine won't start but It will bump start thankfully.
Once the engine is warm it will turn over again on the button. It has started when cold on the button when it hasn't rained. This has me stumped, the battery is good, all voltages are good, connections are solid so what is going on?

1. Won't start after sitting in rain, but will start when engine warm(all on the button)
2. Will bump start in rain
3. Battery and voltages all good
4. Connections all good

Where could the issue lie? Any insight would be great.

Comment: When this happens, is the starter engaging the engine and turning the engine over?

Comment: It doesn't sound like the engine is trying to fire, just starter motor noise. It's odd because it's only happening when it's been in rain.

Comment: there is also a whine coming from the starter motor area which can be heard here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TImgQFqmMx0

Comment: From the video, it sounds like the starter is engaged there full time with the engine. That'd wear out the starter ***fast***.

Comment: Could a bad starter clutch cause this? Could it casue the intermittent starting issues? It happened again today but in dry weather. The starter solenoid checks out good. Thanks